# Laplace Transform

Tags: laplace-transform

The question I had was

> Find the Laplace transform of $$f(t)=10e^{-200t}u(t).$$

Would it be correct to take out the $10$ because it is a constant, find the Laplace transform of $e^{-200t}$ and then multiply it by the Laplace transform of $u(t)$ to obtain a final answer of $$10\left(\frac{1}{s+200}\right)\left(\frac1s\right).$$ The $u(t)$ is what is really confusing me in this problem.

Comment: Laplace transform is linear so yes, transform of 10 times something is 10 times the transform. Laplace Transform is defined for $t\ge0$ so that f(t) and f(t)u(t) have the same transform. See this from the definition of the transform as an integral.

Answer (score 1):

There is an extra $1/s$ in your final formula. Let $f(t) = a e^{-b t} u(t)$ with $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ (I'm assuming your $u(t)$ is the [Heaviside step function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function)). Then

\begin{align}
(L f)(s) &= \int_0^\infty f(t) e^{-s t} \mathrm dt = \int_0^\infty a e^{-b t}e^{- st} u(t)\mathrm  dt \\ &= a \int_0^\infty e^{-(b+s)t} \mathrm dt = \frac{a}{s+b}.
\end{align}
The region of convergence is $s \in \mathbb{C}: \operatorname{Re}(s) > -b$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and no.

It's OK to break out the 10 since the Laplace transform is linear, that is fox $\mathcal L\alpha f = \alpha\mathcal Lf$ for any **constant** $\alpha$.

But to separately transform $e^{-200t}$ and $u(t)$ and multiply the results is wrong. Multiplication under the $\mathcal L$ corresponds to convolution outside it.

However if you're talking about the one-sided laplace transform then the transform of $e^{-200t}u(t)$ is the same as for $e^{-200t}$ since we only integrate over positive numbers anyway. The result would consequently be:

$$\mathcal L 10e^{-200t}u(t) = 10\mathcal Le^{-200t} = 10 {1\over s+200}$$